# Issue with Node-based Cordova Hook

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm playing around with the Cordova hooks capabilities and I'm trying to test using a node application as a hook. In this article: http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/ it references running node applications, so I know it's possible.

I've created a simple node application that I'm using to test the before prepare and after prepare process:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
console.log("this is a node module");
```

When I run my prepare, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\jwargo\dev\lunchmenu>cordova prepare
The system cannot find the path specified.
Hook failed with error code 1: C:\Users\jwargo\dev\lunchmenu\hooks\before_prepare\test.js
```

I can't find any information anywhere about what an error code of 1 means here.

I've tested the node code and it runs fine with "node test.js" and when I execute test.js from the command line Windows simply launches my default editor.

So, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to be able to execute a node application as a hook with the Cordova CLI?

Comment: What version of cordova are you running?  That article was written against 3.0 (I wrote it) but I can't imagine that things have changed that much.

Comment: What happens when you remove the first line (the env line)?

Comment: It's Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.7. I'll try removing that line and get back to you.

Comment: When I remove that first line, it still doesn't work, but I do get a different error:

    Hook failed with error code Unknown system errno 193: C:\Users\jwargo\dev\lunchmenu\hooks\before_prepare\test.js

Comment: Can you try removing the space in between ! and /usr on the first line?  That is, have it be: #!/usr/bin/env node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with some help from the Cordova dev team. The space in my shebang was causing the problem. I removed it and the problem went away.